# Repeater Search Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How can I make my select line in C# check if `news_title` is like my query string named Search?

This is what I have tried without success. It's supposed to then fill a `Repeater` with results that are like the query string.

```
// Get data from database/repository
static DataTable GetDataFromDb()
{
    string searchquery = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Search"].ToString();

    var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
    con.Open();
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [news] WHERE ([news_title] " +
                     "LIKE '%' + " + searchquery + " + '%') Order By news_postdate", con);

    var dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'%" + searchquery + "%'`? Also this kind of string concatenation is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: By the way, beware or SQL injection which may occur with this kind of code.

Comment: S.Akbari i will try your solution, and i dont care about sql injection local project for fun. not getting published.

Comment: S.Akbari if you answer the question ill make your answer mark as working. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should  be `'%" + searchquery + "%'`. However this kind of string concatenation is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead, something like this :

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [news] WHERE [news_title] " +
                            "LIKE @Search Order By news_postdate", con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search","%" + searchquery + "%");
```

Or:

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [news] WHERE [news_title]" +
                            " like '%' + @Search+ '%' Order By news_postdate", con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search",searchquery);
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`. Have a look at this [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)